# Memory Profiler - Google App Engine for Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memory-leaks

I'm using Google App Engine (the Java version).
Is there a way to find out which parts for my code cause high memory consumption ?

I need some kind of memory profiler. As far I know Google's Appstats does not provide this functionality.

Comment: Could you not use VisualVM to look at the JVM and work it out from there potentially?

Comment: http://thoughts.inphina.com/2010/09/04/performance-tuning-java-application-in-google-app-engine/ would be a good point to start

Answer (score 0):

Use the following tools;

- [Java VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html)
- [JMP (Java Memory Profiler)](http://www.khelekore.org/jmp/)